# AWS Step Functions with dynamic steps

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am exploring AWS step functions, however, I am not able to find the answer to a question that my use case requires. Let us say we have 10 tasks we can do in the system overall. Sometimes we have to execute tasks 1, 3 and some times 4, 8 while other times 1, 9, 5 in that order.

The tasks to execute and the order in which they have to execute are determined by incoming json data into the system.

I was wondering if I could somehow dynamically create the step functions based on the needs that arise.

Comment: Could you draw a flow chart (a state machine) for your requirement?
(If yes, you most probably can make a step function)

Comment: Are the flows that you need to execute always the same? Is it always 1 => 3 or 4 => 8 or 1 => 9 => 5?

Comment: @MilanCermak - No. They are not the same and not in the same order always

Comment: @PraneethPeiris - The steps are dynamic. So based on the incoming data, the steps can be in any order.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's all dynamic, you have to get somewhat creative to model the process in Step Functions.

One approach could be to build a state machine with all your tasks in it and a orchestrating `decider` function. The SM would start with the `decider` and then execute the correct job based on its output. Each job would in turn call the `decider` again. If it determines the process is done, the SM would end successfully. This is how it might look:

[image]

```
{
    "StartAt": "Decide next",
    "States": {
        "Decide next": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:::function:decider",
            "ResultPath": "$.nextAction",
            "Next": "Choose action"
        },
        "Choose action": {
            "Type": "Choice",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "Variable": "$.nextAction",
                    "StringEquals": "DONE",
                    "Next": "Process finished"
                },
                {
                    "Variable": "$.nextAction",
                    "StringEquals": "1",
                    "Next": "Job 1"
                },
                {
                    "Variable": "$.nextAction",
                    "StringEquals": "2",
                    "Next": "Job 2"
                },
                {
                    "Variable": "$.nextAction",
                    "StringEquals": "3",
                    "Next": "Job 3"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Job 1": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:::function:job1",
            "ResultPath": "$.jobResult",
            "Next": "Decide next"
        },
        "Job 2": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:::function:job2",
            "ResultPath": "$.jobResult",
            "Next": "Decide next"
        },
        "Job 3": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:::function:job3",
            "ResultPath": "$.jobResult",
            "Next": "Decide next"
        },
        "Process finished": {
            "Type": "Succeed"
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to go through the execution log to see the progress through the SM, you won't be able to see it very well visually (all the jobs that ran will be green, which doesn't tell you about their succession).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking something along the same lines although I didn't know about the green status indicator not showing. Is there any way to run a couple of tasks in parallel? I wasn't able to come up with a solution to that with this kind of setup.

Comment: Yes. There's a `Type: "Parallel"` which allows you to group a bunch of tasks into one step. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html

Comment: But how do we do Parallel dynamically? We probably have to create a step called "Parallel" and another called "Sequential" between the decider and the choose action and let the data drive the flow I suppose right?

Comment: I guess that could work. As I said, you have to be creative on this one as it seems you have a really special use case. An alternative could be that you always create a new Step Function programmatically and then execute it; it doesn't sound like it makes much sense, but I'm just throwing out ideas here :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can alway create a State Machine dynamically. ([from here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/stepfunctions-fluent-api/))

```java
package com.example;

import static com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.builder.StepFunctionBuilder.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.builder.ErrorCodes;

public class StepFunctionsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StateMachine stateMachine = stateMachine()
                .comment("A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using an AWS Lambda Function")
                .startAt("Hello World")
                .state("Hello World", taskState()
                        .resource("arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME")
                        .transition(end()))
                .build();
        System.out.println(stateMachine.toPrettyJson());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is more or less how [Amazon Simple Workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-welcome.html) (SWF) works. I found the documentation a little confusing until I got oriented on the service, at which point things made a lot more sense. I'll try to flatten out the learning curve a little bit here, in the hopes that it's useful:

- SWF is essentially a dynamic [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) engine. If you've ever used [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) (or many other workflow engines), then you know what a DAG is. However, in SWF, your DAG is computed dynamically based on event history, as opposed to declared explicitly as in Airflow or [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).
- Before you can launch a workflow, you have to register a workflow type. This is typically done at design time. It's just a label.
- When you start a workflow, you choose a workflow type. This is just one of the labels you created above.
- When a workflow is started, it has an empty [event history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dev-about-workflow-history.html).
- The way you define your workflow -- i.e., the steps in your DAG -- is by writing a program called a "decider." Your decider spends most of its time in a [long poll for decision tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_PollForDecisionTask.html). When your decider receives a "decision event" via long poll, it should [examine the corresponding workflow's event history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_GetWorkflowExecutionHistory.html), decide what to do next on the basis of that history, and then [tell SWF what you decided](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RespondDecisionTaskCompleted.html). Note that this means your DAG can be the same or different in every execution, depending on how you write your decider.
- When a workflow is started, your decider will receive a decision event immediately, and respond with decisions, like [start an activity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ScheduleActivityTaskDecisionAttributes.html), [start a lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ScheduleLambdaFunctionDecisionAttributes.html), etc. Your decider will then receive a decision event any time those actions have a state change, e.g., scheduled, started, completed, failed, etc., at which point it can respond with decisions to start new actions, and so on. This is an event loop.
- At any time, your decider can [complete the workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_CompleteWorkflowExecutionDecisionAttributes.html), [fail the workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_FailWorkflowExecutionDecisionAttributes.html), and so on as a decision.

As a thought experiment, try to imagine how you could implement Step Functions on top of SWF. When the user defines their state machine using [states language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html), they are creating a data structure that the decider walks to make its decisions in response to state events. The individual actions are "just" activity types inside SWF, and so on. As an aside, I suspect that Step Functions actually are built on top of SWF under the covers, but I don't know that for certain.

SWF also has some more advanced features, like [timers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_StartTimerDecisionAttributes.html) and [signals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_SignalWorkflowExecution.html), but that's the gist of the service.

Circling back to your use case, you would register your 10 task types as [activity types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RegisterActivityType.html) or [lambdas](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). You could then register as many different workflow types as you wanted -- one per job permutation in practice, one top-level workflow, or something in between -- and then define the decider accordingly. The decider(s) would simply "route" the workflow input to the appropriate actions.

Hopefully that made sense! I'm happy to go into more detail if it didn't.