# AWS Step functions for Creating User Driven Workflows

Tags: workflow, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

As a part of the product development, We have to implement a workflow engine. Currently the workflow is simple one i.e , there could be multiple  states for ex: 1,2,3,4,5. The user can select a combination of states for ex

- Work flow 1: 1->2->3->4->5
- Work flow 2: 1->4->5
- Work flow 3: 5

The plan is to implement the  states in the workflow  using Lambdas, ECS Tasks, App Runner etc and the orchestration using Step Functions . Since the workflows are created by users , we are looking for a way to translate the user selection in to a step function state machine.  We are discussing various approaches

- Create a step function programmatically based on the user selection
- Create a catch all work flow with a  Choice , which would a state based on it is selected in the workflow
- Implement a decider function based approach

We found some references in the following post: [AWS Step Functions with dynamic steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472789/aws-step-functions-with-dynamic-steps)

Any other recommendation would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance